# Rails running in development thinks it's in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, development-environment, production-environment

BIt of a weird one this.

```
rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

But when I call

```
puts Rails.env
```

in a controller, it says

```
production
```

In rails console it correctly says development

```
 Rails.env
 => "development"
```

Any ideas. 
I want to run in dev locally and production on my server. Particularly important as I'm testing functionality where it costs me money to run certain api calls and I have them faked if Rails.env.prodcution? is false.
Running rails 3.2.13

Comment: Quick sanity check - Are you hitting localhost:3000 when you see the controller `puts` statement?

Comment: 100% certain on that one... It's running on a terminal on my laptop. Though admittedly worth a check, I've done dumber things.

Comment: Too many times I've been caught not checking the simple things. Only thing I can think of then is a RAILS_ENV=production statement in your config.ru or your shell environment - although that doesn't explain why it says 'starting in development'

Comment: It's sounds like a deeper issue, but trying RAILS_ENV=development rails s might be worth a shot

Comment: Just to confirm. 
Running with 
RAILS_ENV=development rails s 
still gives the same problem. Rails.env still being reported as production.

Comment: Do you see anything like this `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'` in your `config/environment.rb` ?

Comment: No. Nothing that I can find. Very weird and a bit annoying.